# PowerShell XML script issue, name values being overwritten

Tags: xml, powershell

I've written the following script to modify a configuration file for a monitoring application.

basically, there's a particular protocol that is causing .net crashes and stopping the service, so we need to be able to push this script to disable that. but in some cases there are other protocols excluded where they're not used in the environment and don't need to be monitored so i'm trying to retain those exclusions, but it seems that when another "name" value is added, it overwrites the last.

Basically, i'm expecting this to be added

```
<ScannerExclusion>
  <add name="ZeroConfSweep" />
  <add name="AmtScan" />
</ScannerExclusion>
```

and instead i'm getting this

```
<ScannerExclusion>
  <add name="ZeroConfSweep" />
</ScannerExclusion>
```

this is the script, wondering if someone can shed some insight on whats going wrong

```
    # get config file name
    $MWExpertConfigFile = "MWExpertSystem.exe.config"

    # set the full file path
    $MWExpertConfigPath = $OMREGKEY.Path + "Bin\" + $MWExpertConfigFile

    # Load the MWExpertConfig file from the installation directory
    Write-Output "Loading MWExpert Config"
    $MWExpertConfig = [xml](Get-Content $MWExpertConfigPath)

    # Define new element for scanner exclusions
    $ScannerExclusion = $MWExpertConfig.CreateElement("ScannerExclusion")

    # Define an exclusion to add
    $ExclusionAdd = $MWExpertConfig.CreateElement("add")

    # check if any exclusions exist
    if ($MWExpertConfig.configuration.ScannerExclusion -ne $null)
        {
        #find previous exclusion names
        $PreviousExlusions = $MWExpertConfig.configuration.ScannerExclusion.add.name

        Write-Output "Recreating previous exclusions"

        foreach ($name in $PreviousExlusions)
            {
             if ($name -ne "ZeroConfSweep")
                {
                # Set the attribute name and value for the exclusion
                $ExclusionAddAttributeName = $MWExpertConfig.CreateAttribute("name")
                $ExclusionAddAttributeName.Value = $name

                # Append the exclusion attribute to the exclusion element
                $ExclusionAdd.Attributes.Append($ExclusionAddAttributeName)

                $ScannerExclusion.AppendChild($ExclusionAdd)
                }
            }
        }

    # Set the attribute name and value for the exclusion
    Write-Output "Creating exclusion for ZeroConf"
    $ExclusionAddAttributeName = $MWExpertConfig.CreateAttribute("name")
    $ExclusionAddAttributeName.Value = "ZeroConfSweep"

    # Append the exclusion attribute to the exclusion element
    $ExclusionAdd.Attributes.Append($ExclusionAddAttributeName)

    # Append the exclusion element to the Scanner Exclusions element
    $ScannerExclusion.AppendChild($ExclusionAdd)

    # define our insert point
    $InsertPoint = $MWExpertConfig.configuration.appSettings

    # Check if scannerexlusions exist so we can determine whether to append or replace with the new element
    if ($MWExpertConfig.configuration.ScannerExclusion -eq $null)
        {
        # Now append the scanner exclusions element to the configuration tree
        $MWExpertConfig.configuration.InsertAfter($ScannerExclusion,$InsertPoint)
        }
    else
        {
        $ScannerExclusionRefNode = $MWExpertConfig.configuration.ScannerExclusion
        $MWExpertConfig.configuration.ReplaceChild($ScannerExclusion,$ScannerExclusionRefNode)
        }

    # Finally lets save our new config file

    Write-Output "Saving configuration"
    $MWExpertConfig.Save($MWExpertConfigPath)
```

could use a hand

Comment: "AmtScan" doesn't even appear in your code. It's not surprising that it's not being added.

Comment: there's a foreach loop in there to check for previous exclusions, like AmtScan and add them to the new section....I woke up this morning realizing there's probably an easier way to do this than recreating the entire exclusion section though.

Comment: I would recommend looking at .SelectNodes() or .SelectSingleNode() methods on the XmlDocument. Those require some familiarity with XPath, but should simplify your process quite a bit as you won't have to re-add the node.

Comment: I'll have to look into those those function. This is the first time I've worked with XML in powershell. until now I've been doing more administrative type scripts, password resets, creating ad accounts, getting certain system information. I'm finding that working with XML in PW is much different than what I'm used to but at least now I'm getting closer and I think I have a better understanding

Comment: You should provide sample xml before and after script + script(which you have provided), so that we can test and give better answers.

Comment: I actually managed to get it working and reduced the line count as well. I woke up this morning and realized that rather than trying to get each existing item and recreate the node entirely, I should just be trying to append a new item if the parent node already exists. Not sure why I was trying to do it the hard way before, may have been the whisky, but it's working now.